# Swift class that inherits an Objective-C Base Class not casting to correct type

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, inheritance

- Using Xcode 7
- Swift 2

I have been researching inheriting Objective C base class in a Swift UIViewController. I have added my Bridging header file correctly and it is correctly part of my project build settings:

[image]

In my SCS-Bridging-Header.h file I have the following code:

```
#import "UIViewControllerPlus.h"
```

And then I am trying to inherit the Objective C class UIViewControllerPlus in a Swift class:

```
import UIKit

class TestBasicTabBarSegueViewController: UIViewControllerPlus {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

This builds and runs, but when I Segue to the Swift `TestBasicTabBarSegueViewController` a property of the Objective C base class or super class is not accessible:

```
#ifndef UIViewControllerPlus_h
#define UIViewControllerPlus_h

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "MMTabBarController.h"

@interface UIViewControllerPlus : UIViewController
@property MMTabBarController* mt;
@end

#endif /* UIViewControllerPlus_h */
```

It is the property `mt` which is of type MMTabBarController.

You can see in the following custom Segue that destinationController.mt is not accessible and causes the app to crash when attempting to set:

```
#import "MMNavigationSegue.h"
#import "MMTabBarController.h"
#import "UIViewControllerPlus.h"

@implementation MMNavigationSegue

- (void) perform
{
    MMTabBarController *tabBarController = (MMTabBarController *) self.sourceViewController;
    UIViewControllerPlus *destinationController = (UIViewControllerPlus *) self.destinationViewController;
    destinationController.mt = tabBarController; //HERE APP CRASHES

    for (UIView *view in tabBarController.placeholderView.subviews)
    {
        [view removeFromSuperview];
    }

    // Add view to placeholder view
    tabBarController.currentViewController = destinationController;
    [tabBarController.placeholderView addSubview: destinationController.view];

    // Set autoresizing
    [tabBarController.placeholderView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];

    UIView *childview = destinationController.view; 
    [childview setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints: NO];

    // fill horizontal
    [tabBarController.placeholderView addConstraints: [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat: @"H:|[childview]|" options: 0 metrics: nil views: NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(childview)]];

    // fill vertical
    [tabBarController.placeholderView addConstraints:[ NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat: @"V:|-0-[childview]-0-|" options: 0 metrics: nil views: NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(childview)]];

    [tabBarController.placeholderView layoutIfNeeded]; 

    // notify did move
    [destinationController didMoveToParentViewController: tabBarController];
}

@end
```

Note, the above code works if the destination UIViewController Segued to is an Objective C code UIViewController implementation that inherits from the Objective C class `UIViewControllerPlus`.

But on the next line the app crashes:

[image]

Error:

```
2016-06-14 21:16:39.795 SCS[49747:17004544] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIViewController setMt:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7d967080'
```

The destinationController is not casting to type `UIViewControllerPlus` it is instead casting to type `UIViewController`, even though it defined as a `UIViewControllerPlus`. This only happens if it is a Swift file/class inheriting the Objective C `UIViewControllerPlus` class but the cast works if it is Objective C subclass inheriting Objective C base class `UIViewControllerPlus`:

[image]

**Is inheriting an Objective C base class in Swift possible? I have read various conflicting statements online about this?

Is there something I might be missing in my Objective C project references/configuration?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-[UIViewController setMt:]:` means the view controller being instantiated is a regular view controller - not one of your subclassed "plus" type.

You probably forgot to assign the correct class to the view controller in the storyboard.