# Downcasting Objective-C object to Swift type fails (silently)

Tags: objective-c, swift, porting, downcast

This was discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37825865/swift-class-that-inherits-an-objective-c-base-class-not-casting-to-correct-type); similar but not identical.

`MyView` is a Swift subclass of `UIImageView`. It compiles and its interface appears in the `DerivedData/.../*-Swift.h` file. But downcasting to it in Obj-C fails. The code:

```
MyView* myView = (MyView*)viewThatCameFromIB; 
// The Custom Class declared in IB inspector as MyView.
```

results in this line in the Xcode Variable Viewer:

```
myView  UIImageView *  0x7fc8e9417e00
```

This line of code executes with no failure. But sure enough, trying to use the `MyView` features on the `myView` variable crashes with unknown selector. Since the cast succeeded in Obj-C, before `MyClass` was ported, it *should* also after the port, n'est-ce pas?

I tried:

- deleting and resetting the Custom Class in IB just in case.
- breaking this line of code into multiple steps.

Now *this* worked:

- instantiate a `MyView` directly with its `init()` method

That is, I got a `MyView` instance:

```
myView  _TtC12YadaYada11MyView *  0x7f8bc05487d0
```

(Consequently, I can think of a workaround: write a Swift `MyView` constructor that takes a `UIImageView` and uses it to construct itself. But I shouldn't have to. Isn't that what the downcast would do behind the scenes?)

Comment: What custom selectors are you trying to use? I suspect the swift counterparts are formatted slightly differently. Try using autocomplete for them?

Comment: Also, make sure you are using @objc for the exposed functions/attributes.

Comment: A simpler cause might be that `viewThatCameFromIB` really *is* a UIImageView.  Remember that casting doesn't change anything into anything.  All the cast does is tell the compiler what type of object you expect to be dealing with.  The object at run-time doesn't know and doesn't care what you thought it was going to be at compile time.

Comment: @danh but they said to have set the custom class in IB... try to check if when compiling the storyboard/xib you get any warnings, like "MyView symbol not found, resetting to UIImageView"

Comment: @JeshuaLacock, it doesn't matter what selector I use. Xcode (and the runtime) think `myView` is just a plain `UIImageView`. Using @objc has no effect.

Comment: And as @DeFrenZ pointed out, I already set (and cleared and reset) the IB Custom Class. However (new fact) I ran the app in the unported branch and found that the view as coming from IB is *already* a `MyView`. As it should be. So there is something wrong with how the Custom Class is being used in IB. (IOW danh was right. Despite what IB says is the class of `myView`.) Something like the warning message @DeFrenZ suggested. Looks like I will poke around in the .xib raw XML.

Comment: Some more evidence. I looked at the storyboard XML and saw that the Custom Class was set correctly. But along with that were customModule and customModuleProvider. (These were not present in the Obj-C branch because module is a Swift concept.) Now, my understanding of the module setting is incomplete. [continues]

Comment: [continued] My project has two targets: `TargetA` and `TargetB`. The second one does not run because of some assets missing. Has never been run since I forked the repo for porting. All of the `MyView`s were designated as "Inherit Module From Target". But above the checkbox `Target B` appears in gray. And was in the XML. In any case, setting the module by hand to `TargetA` had no effect. But the appearance of a (gray) target name when the checkbox says Inherit From Target seems contradictory. Could be another thread unless somebody can shed light.

Comment: More info: I built a from-scratch test app. It is clear that when the Module setting for a Custom Class does not match the target name, our symptom appears. When they are hard-set to match, or the Inherit Module From Target is set, I get a `MyView` from IB. (And the baffling thing about the grayed-out target always set to the last target persists. Harmless?) So I claim the "answer" to this question is: set the Custom Class module property to Inherit From  Target. Now why this doesn't work on my actual project is unclear. Could be other confounding factors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be caused (fixed) by clearing (setting) the `Inherit Module From Target` boolean for the `MyView` view, in the Custom Class section of the Identity Inspector. At least in the from-scratch test case. In my particular porting challenge, with 3,000+ files (and 50+ `MyView`s), there may be confounding factors. But for now, this is the answer.